# Create new column and assign values from 1 to 100 based on percentiles

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to `pandas` and Python in general.
I have a dataframe with many columns, one of them is `score_init` (may contain duplicate values):

```
+----------+
|score_init|
+----------+
|     38.27|
|     39.27|
|     29.16|
|     32.60|
|     40.45|
|     19.49|
|     48.27|
|     14.25|
|     32.64|
|     32.97|
+----------+
```

For this column I need to calculate percentiles from 0 to 100 and then based on these values create an additional column (`score_new`) where all `score_init` values that lie between 99th and 100th percentiles (`99% < score_init <= 100%`) are assigned 1, between 98th and 99th percentiles (`98% < score <= 99%`) - assigned 2, between 97th and 98th percentiles (`97% < score <= 98%`) - assigned 3, and so on.
For values greater than the 100th percentile, also assign 1; for values less than 0 percentile, assign 100.
Desired output:

```
+----------+----------+
|score_init| score_new|
+----------+----------+
|     38.27|        34|
|     39.27|        23|
|     29.16|        78|
|     32.60|        67|
|     40.45|        12|
|     19.49|        89|
|     48.27|         1|
|     14.25|       100|
|     32.64|        56|
|     32.97|        45|
+----------+----------+
```

**UPDATED**
Entire column values:

```
102, 25, 63, 9, 12, 17, 16, 5, 5, 13, 19, 10, 16, 9, 12, 5, 11, 13, 36, 30, 9, 4, 12, 21, 10, 32, 7, 23, 16, 39, 158, 600, 1682, 125, 99, 116, 22, 10, 60, 15, 8, 6, 7, 26, 19, 10, 8, 15, 34, 4, 33, 13, 15, 16, 16, 16, 5, 5, 73, 76, 102, 8, 9, 19, 64, 9, 8, 6, 9, 6, 70, 58, 42, 19, 40, 23, 27, 741, 47, 26, 24, 32, 22, 46, 51, 67, 39, 3, 26, 139, 25, 20, 16, 11, 100, 19, 22, 8, 47, 46, 16, 5, 42, 28, 19, 10, 9, 54, 133, 29, 39, 8, 10, 49, 112, 13, 8, 10, 18, 134, 6, 153, 11, 10, 8, 20, 37, 17, 17, 28, 34, 17, 15, 19, 29, 92, 16, 12, 15, 14, 46, 23, 10, 5, 32, 11, 19, 18, 5, 64, 42, 5, 62, 40, 12, 12, 14, 26, 10, 20, 26, 33, 23, 23, 24, 54, 18, 15, 24, 32, 34, 14, 59, 3, 45, 4, 19, 11, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 5, 6, 23, 7, 17, 24, 41, 4, 5, 7, 7, 20, 18, 9, 4, 115, 6, 22, 5, 5, 145, 25, 37, 16, 22, 138, 48, 9, 16, 5, 4, 4, 9, 203, 130, 200, 94, 35, 5, 4, 14, 11, 20, 10, 21, 65, 15, 12, 48, 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df['scores_new'] = 100 - pd.qcut(df['score_init'], 100).cat.codes
```

output:

```
   score_init  scores_new
0       38.27          34
1       39.27          23
2       29.16          78
3       32.60          67
4       40.45          12
5       19.49          89
6       48.27           1
7       14.25         100
8       32.64          56
9       32.97          45
```

You can generalize to any quantile, example for quartiles:

```
N = 4
df['scores_new'] = N - pd.qcut(df['score_init'], N).cat.codes
```

###### workaround when duplicated edges

You can manually compute the bins the way `qcut` would to it, but keep the original labels instead of changing the bins:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score_init': [102, 25, 63, 9, 12, 17, 16, 5, 5, 13, 19, 10, 16, 9, 12, 5, 11, 13, 36, 30, 9, 4, 12, 21, 10, 32, 7, 23, 16, 39, 158, 600, 1682, 125, 99, 116, 22, 10, 60, 15, 8, 6, 7, 26, 19, 10, 8, 15, 34, 4, 33, 13, 15, 16, 16, 16, 5, 5, 73, 76, 102, 8, 9, 19, 64, 9, 8, 6, 9, 6, 70, 58, 42, 19, 40, 23, 27, 741, 47, 26, 24, 32, 22, 46, 51, 67, 39, 3, 26, 139, 25, 20, 16, 11, 100, 19, 22, 8, 47, 46, 16, 5, 42, 28, 19, 10, 9, 54, 133, 29, 39, 8, 10, 49, 112, 13, 8, 10, 18, 134, 6, 153, 11, 10, 8, 20, 37, 17, 17, 28, 34, 17, 15, 19, 29, 92, 16, 12, 15, 14, 46, 23, 10, 5, 32, 11, 19, 18, 5, 64, 42, 5, 62, 40, 12, 12, 14, 26, 10, 20, 26, 33, 23, 23, 24, 54, 18, 15, 24, 32, 34, 14, 59, 3, 45, 4, 19, 11, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 5, 6, 23, 7, 17, 24, 41, 4, 5, 7, 7, 20, 18, 9, 4, 115, 6, 22, 5, 5, 145, 25, 37, 16, 22, 138, 48, 9, 16, 5, 4, 4, 9, 203, 130, 200, 94, 35, 5, 4, 14, 11, 20, 10, 21, 65, 15, 12, 48, 18]})


q = 100
quantiles = np.linspace(0, 1, q + 1)
bins = np.quantile(df['score_init'], quantiles)
bins, labels = np.unique(bins, return_index=True)
df['scores_new'] = 100 - pd.cut(df['score_init'], bins=bins, labels=labels[:-1]).astype('Int64')
```

output:

```
     score_init  scores_new
0           102           8
1            25          36
2            63          13
3             9          79
4            12          67
..          ...         ...
229          65          12
230          15          62
231          12          67
232          48          18
233          18          51
```